# Change value of a scrollbar

Tags: c#, int, hex, rgb, scrollbars

I'm creating a Color Picker, and I have an "Input" and "Output". In the input I have 4 scrollbars, and in the output I have a preview, and 3 textboxes with the output.

When you click on the preview, a windows will open with a color dialog. It's works fine with hex and returns a hex value.

But, I want to put the hex value that it returns in the scrollbars.

I think that I'll have to convert it to RGB or Int, then set the scrollbar values.

How can I do that?

Code from the pictureBox:

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
            string color, colorRGB;
            color = string.Format("{0:X8}", pictureBox1.BackColor.ToArgb());
            colorRGB = string.Format("{0:X6}", pictureBox1.BackColor.ToArgb());
            hexResult = color;
            pawnTextBox.Text = "#define " + colorNameTxtBox.Text + " 0x" + hexResult;
            hexTextBox.Text = "0x" + hexResult;
        }
    }
```

Code from the scrollbars:

```
    private void alphaScroll_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        Color previewColor = Color.FromArgb(alphaScroll.Value, redScroll.Value, greenScroll.Value, blueScroll.Value);
        pictureBox1.BackColor = previewColor;

        int colorHex = alphaScroll.Value | (blueScroll.Value << 8) | (greenScroll.Value << 16) | (redScroll.Value << 24);
        hexResult = "0x" + string.Format("{0:X}", colorHex.ToString("X8"));

        hexTextBox.Text = hexResult;
        pawnTextBox.Text = "#define " + colorNameTxtBox.Text + " " + hexResult;
        alphaResultLabel.Text = alphaScroll.Value.ToString();
    }

    private void redScroll_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        Color previewColor = Color.FromArgb(alphaScroll.Value, redScroll.Value, greenScroll.Value, blueScroll.Value);
        pictureBox1.BackColor = previewColor;

        int colorHex = alphaScroll.Value | (blueScroll.Value << 8) | (greenScroll.Value << 16) | (redScroll.Value << 24);
        hexResult = "0x" + string.Format("{0:X}", colorHex.ToString("X8"));

        int red = redScroll.Value;
        int green = greenScroll.Value;
        int blue = blueScroll.Value;

        getColorTxtBox.Text = red.ToString("X2") + green.ToString("X2") + blue.ToString("X2");
        embeddTextBox.Text = "{" + red.ToString("X2") + green.ToString("X2") + blue.ToString("X2") + "}";
        hexTextBox.Text = hexResult;
        pawnTextBox.Text = "#define " + colorNameTxtBox.Text + " " + hexResult;
        redResultLabel.Text = redScroll.Value.ToString();
    }

    private void greenScroll_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        Color previewColor = Color.FromArgb(alphaScroll.Value, redScroll.Value, greenScroll.Value, blueScroll.Value);
        pictureBox1.BackColor = previewColor;

        int colorHex = alphaScroll.Value | (blueScroll.Value << 8) | (greenScroll.Value << 16) | (redScroll.Value << 24);
        hexResult = "0x" + string.Format("{0:X}", colorHex.ToString("X8"));

        int red = redScroll.Value;
        int green = greenScroll.Value;
        int blue = blueScroll.Value;

        getColorTxtBox.Text = red.ToString("X2") + green.ToString("X2") + blue.ToString("X2");
        embeddTextBox.Text = "{" + red.ToString("X2") + green.ToString("X2") + blue.ToString("X2") + "}";
        hexTextBox.Text = hexResult;
        pawnTextBox.Text = "#define " + colorNameTxtBox.Text + " " + hexResult;
        greenResultLabel.Text = greenScroll.Value.ToString();
    }

    private void blueScroll_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        Color previewColor = Color.FromArgb(alphaScroll.Value, redScroll.Value, greenScroll.Value, blueScroll.Value);
        pictureBox1.BackColor = previewColor;

        int colorHex = alphaScroll.Value | (blueScroll.Value << 8) | (greenScroll.Value << 16) | (redScroll.Value << 24);
        hexResult = "0x" + string.Format("{0:X}", colorHex.ToString("X8"));

        int red = redScroll.Value;
        int green = greenScroll.Value;
        int blue = blueScroll.Value;

        getColorTxtBox.Text = red.ToString("X2") + green.ToString("X2") + blue.ToString("X2");
        embeddTextBox.Text = "{" + red.ToString("X2") + green.ToString("X2") + blue.ToString("X2") + "}";
        hexTextBox.Text = hexResult;
        pawnTextBox.Text = "#define " + colorNameTxtBox.Text + " " + hexResult;
        blueResultLabel.Text = blueScroll.Value.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide your code and clearly state your question.

Comment: I don't know what code to provide, the code is big.

I have 4 scrollbars (Alpha, red, green and blue) and want to put a hex value on it. But i'll have to use integer to it, and i dont know how can I do that.

Comment: Can you make your scrollbars have a `minimum` value of `0` and a `maximum` of `255`? Then do some conversion from there?

Comment: Already did, I'll add some code from them in the question.

Comment: I have rolled back the question to before the "question" code was removed. If you have solved your own problem, *post and answer*, don't replace your question. I have taken the "answer" out of your question and made it an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for that in .NET:

```
Color c = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hmtlcolor);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Disclamer: this was posted in the question by the author, replacing the code in question. I've rolled back the question and placed the solved code here, as a community wiki answer.*

---

If someone is getting the same question that I am, here's the solution:

```
string c = color.ToString();
string redHex = c.Substring(0, 2);
string greenHex = c.Substring(2, 2);
string blueHex = c.Substring(4, 2);
string alphaHex = c.Substring(6, 2);

int red = Convert.ToInt32(redHex, 16);
int green = Convert.ToInt32(greenHex, 16);
int blue = Convert.ToInt32(blueHex, 16);
int alpha = Convert.ToInt32(alphaHex, 16);

alphaScroll.Value = alpha;
redScroll.Value = red;
greenScroll.Value = green;
blueScroll.Value = blue;

alphaResultLabel.Text = alphaScroll.Value.ToString();
redResultLabel.Text = redScroll.Value.ToString();
greenResultLabel.Text = greenScroll.Value.ToString();
blueResultLabel.Text = blueScroll.Value.ToString();
```